# html code did not work after AddType in htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

When tried to add

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

in my htaccess file my PHP code starts to display normally (while my file extensions is .html) but other html codes is not working can you help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify your current php version,try :

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .htm .html
```

Or you can also add php handler to `.htm` or `html` files using mod-rewrite :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \.html?$ - [H=application/x-httpd-php5,L]
```

Comment: As i mentioned above my PHP code is working in after adding

Comment: Thanks after researching i found out that there is an error on my PHP inlude codes